# Do you keep your items from custom maps when you return to your world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On some custom maps in Minecraft they give you items. Can you keep these items to bring back to your main world?

Answer (score 5):

## No

Whenever you play on a custom map, you play in a *different save file* from any game you play on any other map (like your "main world"). Nothing persists between save files, so any item you get in one will **not** carry over to the other.